# how to get Carrier details on mango?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any API which can gives us phone is on which carrier(ex: vodafone)? home country, current country, details?

I couldn't find any such in Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation, am i missing something?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this via the static property [DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.cellularmobileoperator%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Remember that there may not always be one - in which case it returns null.

You can also get the [device name and manufacturer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus_properties%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) or the current country via the [Location services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431803%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

The nearest you'de be able to get to a "home country" would be via the regional settings.

Comment: ok, while working on these, i found something interesting. When i try to use socketExtensionMethods, I get MissingMethodException as "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.SocketExtensionMethods' from assembly 'Microsoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24EEC0D8C86CDA1E'." which works fine on emulator :(

Comment: @rplusg is your phone running the same version of mango as the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

In Mango, i.e. the next release, does have a static class called [DeviceNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh203231%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
It provides CellularMobileOperator which is the name of the carier.

Comment: Looks like details we can get are very minimal.