# Accessing carrier information windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get Carrier details on mango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954718/how-to-get-carrier-details-on-mango)

Is it possible to get the carrier information in a windows phone? 
I want to show the carrier name in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the carrier name by using DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator.

Refer [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202875%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can access this information using `DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator`.

[DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.cellularmobileoperator%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

```
var operatorName = DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator ?? "(No Network)";
```

Since the property may be `null` in the case of no network being found, the above code will get you either the network operator or `(No Network)` into `operatorName`.